# UIImage ScaleToFit disable antialias?

Tags: iphone, antialiasing

[image: antialiasing in UIImage scale to fit]

is there any way to disable antialiasing when scaling images in uiimage? thanks

Comment: For google's sake, this is also called bitmap smoothing, anti aliasing, sampling, upsampling, downsampling, resampling, and making pixels sharp when scaling or a scale transform is applied.  =)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add the QuartzCore framework to your project, then set the image view’s `layer`’s `magnificationFilter` property to `kCAFilterNearest`.

Comment: For MonoTouch users this constant is available under: CALayer.FilterNearest

Answer (score 3):

I was working with SpriteKit in Xcode 11 (Swift 5) and also got this problem. To solve it (i.e. disable anti-aliasing) i did the following:

```
texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
```