# How to display a pixel art image in Xcode 7 without it anti-Aliasing

Tags: swift, image, rendering, xcode7, antialiasing

I'm new to Xcode so please be patient with me! :)

(using Swift 2.1, OSX 10.11.2 El Capitan and Xcode 7.2 I am not using sprite kit or anything like that, I'm just using a single page application)

I'm trying to make a pixel art game but whenever I create a UIImageView and set the image to my pixel art png file, it makes the image all blurry, here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

as you can see in the Preview window (right) the image is crisp and clean, and in the Xcode window (left) the image is blurry and fuzzy

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092167/uiimage-scaletofit-disable-antialias

Comment: thanks! all I did was: "image.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest"

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5 you can do the following to change the filtering mode:

```
texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
```

This will disable anti-aliasing for the selected texture.

Comment: The question specifically states that SpriteKit is not being used.

Answer (score -2):

This should not be an issue.

1. Check the view mode of the Image. Try setting it to center.
   [image]

You can also turn off the PNG Compression. [How can I skip compressing one PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051947/how-can-i-skip-compressing-one-png).

It is possible that the alpha channel is messing it up so try saving as a 24 bit PNG no Alpha or even better 8bit PNG no Alpha.

Comment: I realised the best way to do it, is to just scale the image -in PS or whatever graphic editing software you use- to about 3200%. That should be big enough to prevent any anti-aliasing, without the need to write any code